# Replacing Icons in body with Pages in Flutter Gallery Example of BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

I am using the Flutter Gallery example of `BottomNavigationBar`. Whenever I click on the icons, the body part shows the icons itself. I want to replace all these icons with new pages like `FirstTab()`, `SecondTab()` etc. Can anyone help me out to integrate these pages into the code below?

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:adminify/tabs/first.dart';
import 'package:adminify/tabs/second.dart';
import 'package:adminify/tabs/third.dart';
import 'package:adminify/tabs/fourth.dart';
import 'package:adminify/tabs/fifth.dart';

class NavigationIconView {
  NavigationIconView({
    Widget icon,
    Widget activeIcon,
    String title,
    Color color,
    TickerProvider vsync,
  }) : _icon = icon,

       _title = title,
       item = BottomNavigationBarItem(
         icon: icon,
         activeIcon: activeIcon,
         title: Text(title),
         backgroundColor: color,
       ),
       controller = AnimationController(
         duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
         vsync: vsync,
       ) {
    _animation = controller.drive(CurveTween(
      curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
    ));
  }

  final Widget _icon;

  final String _title;
  final BottomNavigationBarItem item;
  final AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  FadeTransition transition(BottomNavigationBarType type, BuildContext context) {
    Color iconColor;
      final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
      iconColor = themeData.brightness == Brightness.light
          ? themeData.primaryColor
          : themeData.accentColor;


    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animation,
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animation.drive(
          Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.02), // Slightly down.
            end: Offset.zero,
          ),
        ),
        child: IconTheme(
          data: IconThemeData(
            color: iconColor,
            size: 120.0,
          ),
          child: Semantics(
            label: 'Placeholder for $_title tab',
            child: _icon,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavigationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/material/bottom_navigation';

  @override
  _BottomNavigationDemoState createState() => _BottomNavigationDemoState();
}

class _BottomNavigationDemoState extends State<BottomNavigationDemo>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  BottomNavigationBarType _type = BottomNavigationBarType.fixed;
  List<NavigationIconView> _navigationViews;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigationViews = <NavigationIconView>[
      NavigationIconView(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
        title: 'Home',
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(

        activeIcon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
        title: 'Explore',
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(
        activeIcon: const Icon(Icons.cloud),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.cloud_queue),
        title: 'Cloud',
        color: Colors.teal,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(
        activeIcon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
        title: 'Saved',
        color: Colors.indigo,
        vsync: this,
      ),
      NavigationIconView(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.event_available),
        title: 'Profile',
        color: Colors.pink,
        vsync: this,
      )
    ];

    _navigationViews[_currentIndex].controller.value = 1.0;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {   
    for (NavigationIconView view in _navigationViews)
      view.controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();

  }

  Widget _buildTransitionsStack() {
    final List<FadeTransition> transitions = <FadeTransition>[];

    for (NavigationIconView view in _navigationViews)
      transitions.add(view.transition(_type, context));

    // We want to have the newly animating (fading in) views on top.
    transitions.sort((FadeTransition a, FadeTransition b) {
      final Animation<double> aAnimation = a.opacity;
      final Animation<double> bAnimation = b.opacity;
      final double aValue = aAnimation.value;
      final double bValue = bAnimation.value;
      return aValue.compareTo(bValue);
    });

    return Stack(children: transitions);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BottomNavigationBar botNavBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      items: _navigationViews
          .map<BottomNavigationBarItem>((NavigationIconView navigationView) => navigationView.item)
          .toList(),
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      type: _type,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _navigationViews[_currentIndex].controller.reverse();
          _currentIndex = index;
          _navigationViews[_currentIndex].controller.forward();
        });
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(

      body: Center(
        child: _buildTransitionsStack()
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: botNavBar,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have buildTransitionStack in your code? That's probably unnecessary unless you're doing something weird. And it seems like you're just starting out with flutter, so it might be worth sticking to the example code for now, getting what you want built, and then worrying about custom animations or transitions after that.

If you look at the [Scrollable Tabs example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/scrollable_tabs_demo.dart) from the gallery, you'll see it has a `body: TabBarView`.  It uses `children: _allPages.map<Widget>((_Page page) {` and within that builds a card with a centered icon. In that example, all you need to do is replace the part that builds the card with whatever it is you want to show in your page.

If you need to use the code you have above, you should spend some time cleaning it up a bit as it seems to be a bit of a mess. But to do what you want, first you need to add a `Widget page` or something like it to NavigationIconView, define that for each of the instances of NavigationIconview (i.e. FirstTab, SecondTab, etc), and then in the `transition` function where you currently have `child: IconTheme( .... child: Icon`, you would instead pass in the page.